# Error con JS/JQuery cuando abro mi vista en internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, c#, jquery

resulta que cuando abro mi vista en IE (debo ocupar ie por que ocupo ActiveXObject y guardo como parametros algunas configuraciones de mi pc), me tira este error

> Excepción no controlada en línea 10, columna 122581 en http://localhost:53465/Content/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js
>   0x800a138f - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: No se puede obtener la propiedad 'length' de referencia nula o sin definir

es justo en esta columna de codigo:

```
{"string"==typeof t?t=document.getElementById(t)
```

Me dan error dos vistas, este el error 1:

```
Excepción no controlada en línea 2, columna 82464 en http://localhost:53465/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

0x800a01b6 - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'indexOf'

este es el script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl').load(function () {
            var btnstat = $(this).attr('id');
            var url = $('#myMod-' + btnstat).data('url');
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $("#myMod-" + btnstat).html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

y por el Chart, la verdad no me da ningun signo de error, solo el {"string"==typeof t?t=document.getElementById(t).

script chart:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Dashboard/NuevoGrafico",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (mems) {
        var aData = mems;
        var aLabels = aData[0];
        var aDatasets1 = aData[1];
        var dataT = {
            labels: aLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Tarjetas emitidas",
                data: aDatasets1,
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
                borderColor: ["rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
                borderWidth: 1,
            }]
        };
        var ctx = $("#mChart1").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: dataT,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: { display: true, text: 'Cantidad de Tarjetas emitidas' },
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' } }],
                    yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' }, ticks: { stepSize: 40, beginAtZero: true } }]
                },

            }
        });                    

    }
});
```

Espero se entienda

Comment: el error no es propiamente en ese archivo, el error es porque no puede leer u obtener el length "longitud" para generar tu grafico con chartJs...

Comment: ahora deberias agregar tu codigo javascript como generas ese grafico

Comment: Listo Diego, se agradece

Comment: Estaba probando y saque el script con el llamado al chart, me da solo el error  Excepción no controlada en línea 10, columna 122581 en http://localhost:53465/Content/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js 0x800a138f - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: No se puede obtener la propiedad 'length' de referencia nula o sin definir